# Android applications restarts device on delete

Tags: android

I am building my own application and debugging it on my Nexus 5. It has a IntentService and some screens. Problem is when I try to uninstall it it reboots my device. After reboot the app is still present, but now I can remove it without problem. Can I debugg this behavior somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're not calling system service that could result in rebooting or an error ?
Have you tried other phones?

Comment: What do you mean by system service ? No I did not tried other phones yet.

Comment: Are you using custom ROM? Try different phones(you can use Emulator but real phone would be better) if that doesn't work,you need to show us some code

Comment: @Cgdl nope, just stock latest lollipop available (not 5.1). No system services I have an IntentService to read some data from storage but that is all.

Comment: I really don't know,it could be because of Lollipop but I doubt it...can you show us some code?